# How does ActiveRecord handle multiple column queries on the same entry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In terms of efficiency, is it better to do this:

```
child = @user.child
foo1 = entry.foo1
foo2 = entry.foo2
```

or

```
foo1 = @user.child.foo1
foo2 = @user.child.foo2
```

where `@user` and `Child` have a one-to-one association.

How exactly do these queries work in Rails, specifically ActiveRecord? Does Rails save a reference implicitly to `@user.entry` inside the controller instance, or does Rails do multiple DB queries?

Secondly, does it depend on the ORM/DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your examples will trigger 3 queries (if no `#includes`)

The first on for `#child` and two others for `#foo1` and `#foo2`.

If you call N times the `#child` method on your user object, it will trigger only one database query, because ActiveRecord will cache the child object into your user object the first time you asked for child.

ActiveRecord will behave the same if you're using PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite, etc.
But other ORM's might not be implemented this way.